# Typescript, Set Style of element in html

Tags: html, css, typescript, ionic-framework

My Problem is that i have a HTML, Type Script combination.

```
   <ion-card class="ionCard" *ngFor="let item of libraries">
      <ion-card-header>
        {{getLibraryName(item.locationName)}}
      </ion-card-header>        
      <ion-card-content>
          <label>{{item.occupiedSeats}} von {{item.freeSeats + item.occupiedSeats}}</label>
        <div class="progressBar">
        <div class="progressBarFilled" style="width:50%"></div>    
        </div>                                
      </ion-card-content>
</ion-card>
```

As you can see in the div with the `class= progressBarFilled` I'm setting a fixed width. I want to set this width dynamic instead. So that i can say `width = {{item.occupiedSeats/item.freeSeats}}`.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either bind to the width property:

```
<div class="progressBarFilled" [style.width]="(item.occupiedSeats/item.freeSeats) + '%'"></div>
```

Or if you always want to use percentage then you can bind directly to that:

```
<div class="progressBarFilled" [style.width.%]="(item.occupiedSeats/item.freeSeats)"></div>
```

Or use the [NgStyle directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) to bind the value:

```
<div class="progressBarFilled" [ng-style]="{'width': (item.occupiedSeats/item.freeSeats) + '%'}"></div>
```